# Should we improve the fibonacci-numbers tag wiki to allow for variations in $F_0$?

Tags: discussion, tag-wikis, convention

The [Fibonacci Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) can be defined in different ways.

$$F_0 = 0; F_1 = 1$$

$$F_0 = 1; F_1 = 1$$

It doesn’t really matter.

However, the [fibonacci-numbers](/questions/tagged/fibonacci-numbers) tag wiki says unequivocally that $F_0 = 1$, while the excerpt says equally firmly that $F_0 = 0$. Should both wiki and excerpt be edited to be a little more open to variation?

Comment: There are many properties of the Fibonacci numbers that rely on $F_0=0$ such as $F_k\mid F_{kn}$.

Comment: It is better to have $F_0$ defined as zero in order to have $\gcd(F_n,F_m)=F_{\gcd(n,m)}$ and other nice identities.

Comment: [Integer sequences](http://oeis.org/A000045) gives the sequence of Fibonacci numbers as $(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144,\cdots)$.

Comment: Why this was migrated, actually? This question is about editing tag wiki.

Comment: You're right, @GrigoryM. I've flagged it asking for a mod to move it back to meta.

Comment: (about tag wiki excerpt contradicting tag wiki)

Comment: While technically not the proper name, I do think that allowing variations is natural and good.

Comment: Well, it looks like I picked up 20 rep in that weird time when this question moved meta -> main -> meta.

Comment: When I migrated this from meta to math, the title was ["Where do the Fibonacci numbers begin?"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2inpk.png) There was a link to the tag-wiki, but it was not a meta question when it was migrated to math.

Comment: I invite you to reread the actual body of the question, @robjohn.

Comment: I would avoid putting alternate definitions in the tag-wiki. Choose one and stick to it. It's not like someone's not going to ask a question because the tag has a shifted initial condition - in all likelyhood, they read the tag-wiki after posting the question (if at all). (Hey, even stick $F_0=0$, $F_1=1$ and $F_2=1$ for clarity to anyone who's not aware of the shift, if you want)

Comment: I think Fibonacci numbers deserve their own tag, since they are of significant interest independently of other related sequences. But perhaps questions about other sequences (Lucas numbers, etc.) deserve a general tag of their own. The [sequences-and-series] tag is overused in my opinion; it draws questions from calculus (convergence and summability) and combinatorics/number theory that have little to do with one another. I suggest the creation of an [integer-sequences] tag (I was sure there would be one!) to cover the latter case.

Comment: @neuguy Other sequences defined by recurrence relations naturally fall under [recurrence-relations](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recurrence-relations) tag. So do the Fibonacci numbers, but they appear to be sufficiently famous to also have own tag.

Comment: Motivation for such conventions is already discussed in prior main questions, e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/678919/242) and [here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/92393/242)

Answer (score 16):

I suggest that we adopt the convention that $F_0=0$ for both the tag wiki and summary, with a possible note in the wiki that $F_0=1$ is occasionally used as well.

**Why?**  This is consistent with [OEIS A000045](http://oeis.org/A000045) and it results in a nice form of [Binet's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinetsFibonacciNumberFormula.html) (as opposed to a offset in the exponents).  Other properties (as mentioned in the comments) rely on a starting value of $0$.

Comment: There is no advantage to having $F_0=1$.

Comment: @Alizter If you define $F_n$ as the number of tilings of $1 \times n$ rectangle by $1 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ tiles (which seems like a pretty natural definition) then you get $F_0 = F_1 = 1$.  But I think it is obvious on the whole that $F_0 = 0$ is better.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest describing something like as follows:

> Fibonacci Numbers are consecutive elements of the Fibonacci Sequence: $F_0=0, F_1=1, F_{n+1}=F_n+F_{n-1} (n\gt 0)$

ie distinguishing Fibonacci Numbers, where the indexing is irrelevant, from ***the*** Fibonacci Sequence, where canonical indexing is expected.