# Why are empty tags not going away?

Tags: bug, tagging, tag-management

As far as I understand, [empty tags should be removed after 24h](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112519/empty-tags-with-no-questions). But right now, the tags [geometric-modeling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-modeling) and [cycle-index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycle-index) are still around even though I'm 100% certain that they have been empty for much more than 24h. There is also [chain-rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain-rule), but I don't know for sure that it has been emptied less than 24h ago. What is going on?

Even stranger is the case of [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged). [This question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18876/should-we-improve-the-fibonacci-numbers-tag-wiki-to-allow-for-variations-in-f-0) was migrated twice, once to main then back to meta. When it was migrated to main, since the tag discussion doesn't exist there, it was marked untagged. When it was migrated back, it apparently stayed around somewhere in the DB and fills up the tag [untagged](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) (see for yourself), which cannot disappear now.

Comment: A shout-out to [this bug report](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/16552/using-tag-markup-in-posts-creates-an-ugly-gap-between-lines), writing questions about tags is always annoying.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the script for removal of tags runs daily, and removes tags that have not been used for 24 hours before the script runs, so in case of unfortunate timing, it could take up to 48 hours to have the tag removed. Is the "much more than 24h" also more than 48h? Also, it might be that in the interim there appeared a question with the tag which was then removed, which would delay the removal of the tag (not very likely, but possible).

Comment: +1, especially for [tag:untagged].

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes, it's been at least three days.

Comment: Aha. Strange. We have [a lot of empty tags](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags?page=33&tab=popular), but most of them are synonyms - [tag:untagged] is special, it's baked into the system, needed for some migrations (I don't know if it ever goes away completely and is re-created when needed, or it stays regardless).

Comment: [tag:chain-rule] was [removed here seven hours ago](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1082059/5), so that's not been unused long enough.

Comment: @DanielFischer [tag:untagged] is removed by the 03:00 UTC auto-deleter (just like regular tags) and is recreated as needed, fwiw.

Comment: @senshin Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[cycle-index](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cycle-index) was used recently, it was removed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1072319/2) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1070239/4) seven hours ago.

[geometric-modeling](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/geometric-modeling) was also used recently, removed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/1076974/5) (and possibly elsewhere) by the same user at approximately the same time.

[Eric Stucky](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/31888/eric-stucky) also cleared [chain-rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chain-rule) at around the same time. Thanks to him for cleaning up some tags.

Comment: Thanks. (Also thanks to robjohn for [fixing the "untagged" tag](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1078954/revisions))